# Waiting for a file to exist in a directory C#

Tags: c#, directory, file-exists, visual-c#-express-2010

I am creating a `Visual C# application` and part of its functionality is to extract a `.gz` file once it appears in a directory. The `.gz` file appears in the specified directory once a command line argument is executed.

Unfortunately, I receive an error saying something along the lines of "this file cannot be found" and this is due to the reason that it reads the line to extract the `.gz` file too quickly.

In other words, it is trying to execute a `.gz` file before the command line argument executes and actually places the file into the directory.

I want to find a way for my program to wait for the file to appear in the directory before it continues to read the next line.

Below is my code, any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

```
else if (ddlDateType.Text == "Monthly" || ddlDateType.Text == "")
{
    //Check if Monthly date entered is valid
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate.Text, MonthlyFormat, null,
        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out Test) != true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid date.\nFormat: yyyyMM");
    }
    else
    {
        //Method that executes an arugment into the command prompt
        ExecuteCommand();

        //Method that extracts the file after it has already appeared in the directory
        ExtractFile();

        /*
        Goal is to wait for the file to appear in the directory before it executes
        the ExtractFile() method.
         */

    }
}
```

Comment: My first thought is to just do `while (!File.Exists(theFile)) { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); }`

Answer (score 5):

you can use FileSystemWatcher. https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

in this example, the callback OnChanged, is called every time a file was added to the monitored folder.

```
   [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
    public static void RunWathcer()
    {

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        watcher.Path = "PATH TO WATCH GOES HERE!!";

        /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
           the renaming of files or directories. */
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        watcher.Filter = "*.*";

        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    // Define the event handlers.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
       Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Playing devil's advocate: what happens if something OTHER than the file needed is changed in this directory path? Would it not fail then?

Comment: obviously you have to filter for the expected file name and so on... i'm proposing a possible solution, i do not see all program then i cannot forecast :-)

Comment: I did not know that this FileSystemWatcher class existed. I can see this being useful. @Gary The watcher.Filter looks like it can be set to look for the specific file or file extension if the name is dynamic.

Comment: yes, right, details about how to here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DaniloCalzetta Twas not criticising at all, I was simply asking :).

Comment: @JaredStroeb I see that now. I was just curious if possibly it might fire if something else changes or if can only look in directories and not at certain files. It's new to me as well :).